# Custom FormBuilderInterface Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony

I got FormType on symfony:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('statement', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Enunciado:',
            "required"=>"required", "attr"=>array(
                "class" => "form-name form-control"
            )))
        ->add('period', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Periodo:',
            'choices'  => array(
                '2017-2018' => "1718",
                '2018-1029' => "1819"
            ),
            "required"=>"required", "attr"=>array(
                "class" => "form-name form-control"
            )))
        ->add('questiontype', ChoiceType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Tipo de pregunta:',
            'choices'  => array(
                'Test' => "test",
                'Relacion' => "relacion",
                'Desarrolo' => "desarrollo",
                'Verdadero-Falso' => "truefalse",
            ), "attr"=>array(
                "class" => "form-password form-control"
            )))
        ->add('image', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Añadir imagen'))
        ->add('Registrar',SubmitType::class, array("attr"=>array(
            "class" => "form-submit btn btn-success"
        )));
}
```

I would like to make FileType input visible just in case they choose "Desarrolo".

Is there anyway to do that?
I was thinking on some javascript but if i use FormBuilder i don't know got to do it.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Check this official doc [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/3.3/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case you should use two form events:

- PreSetData: in order to display your `FileType` if the question type is already set to "Desarrolo".
- PostSubmit: in order to add the `FileType` after the form submission.

Maybe something like this:

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddFileFieldPreSetDataSubscriber());

$builder->get('questiontype')->addEventSubscriber(new AddFileFieldPostSubmitSubscriber());
```